# How can I decouple a group from the related organization

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have an organization in which I created a site. So the site belongs to the organization, as stated in the Site Memberships page:

> This site belongs to Jobyourself which is an organization of type booster-club. All users of Jobyourself are automatically members of the site and site roles are automatically assigned to them based on the organization roles they have in Jobyourself as shown in the table below.

I would now like to delete the organization, but keep the site. How can I decouple the group from the related organization (programmatically or through the control panel) ?

I am using liferay 6.1 GA3.

Best regards,
Alain

Answer (score 0):

Alain, From Control Panel navigate to your Site which you want to decouple, From Action button click on Site Membership you should see Organization Tab where you can remove the organization linking.. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ankit. Your solution however does not apply to my case: the organization is not a member of the site, the site is the one related to the organization (in Site Memberships, I see the message "this site belongs to OrganizationName which is an organization of type XYZ..."